# Project Euler Sum of all even numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to find the sum of all even numbers of the fibonacci below 4 mil.
This is my code so far. It is showing me a number but project Euler is saying it is wrong.
Could anyone give some suggestions?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(fibonacci());

}

public static int count(){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i =0; i<1000;i++){
        if(i%3==0||i%5==0){
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}


public static long fibonacci(){

    ArrayList<Integer> even = new ArrayList<Integer>();



    int first = 1;
    int second = 1;
    int third = 0;
    long sum = 0;

    while(!(third>=3999999)){

        third = first+second;
        first = second;
        second = third;
        if(first%2==0){
            even.add( new Integer(first));

        }
        if(second%2==0){
            even.add( new Integer(second));

        }
        if(third%2==0){
            even.add( new Integer(third));

        }


    }
    for(int i = 0; i<=even.size()-1;i++){

        sum+=even.get(i);
    }
    return sum;

}
```

Comment: why is fibonacci related to this????

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Fibonacci if your question is accurate. Can give you the proper code to complete this puzzle, but that kind of defeats the purpose. Just know that it has nothing to do with Fibonacci.

Comment: Your code seems to be adding up some subset of the Fibonacci numbers.  I'm sure that's not what you intended.

Comment: I supoose OP wasn't able to clearly express his question, the original question refers to adding all even number who are in the Fibonacci series. See here for question [link](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2)

Comment: `!(third>=3999999)` is equivalent to `third<3999999`. Is it right?

Comment: @Coldspeed Please do not create meta tags.  We've burned [project-euler] before: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have wrote the incomplete question, the original problem statement is to find sum of all even number who are part of Fibonacci series as well.
2. I would suggest you to first add all the number in the Fibonacci series and then next check of they are even and then add it to a new variable in next loop.

---

```
class Euler2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long n1=0,n2=1,n3,i,j;
        long sum = n1 + n2;
        for(i =2 ;i < 250; i++) {
            if (n3 > 40000000) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                n3 = n1 + n2;
                if (n3%2 == 0) {
                    sum += n3;
                }
                n1 = n2;
                n2 = n3;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("sum of all values: "+sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to store the numbers in a list first, just add them to the sum directly.

Comment: @tobias_k, thanks, it would essentially remove the overhead of using the last for-loop. Just have to add the number to sum in the if condition block; have edited the answer according to that.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of all even numbers

```
long sum = 0
for (int x = 1; x <= 200; x++) {
   if (x % 2 == 0)
     sum += x;
}
```

I do not know what your logic is.

Also I think the result needs to be put in a long

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code:

- you are effectively checking whether the number is `< 3999999`, whereas the problem asks for numbers `<= 4000000` (although that does not change the result)
- no need to manually convert those `int` to `Integer`, and even *if*, you should not use `new Integer` but [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) to make use of caching
- you could simplify the final loop to `for (Integer n : even) {sum += n;}`...
- ... but you don't actually need to store all those numbers in a list before calculating the sum
- and the *actual* problem: You are adding each number *three times* to the list: first when it's `third`, then when it moved to `second`, and finally when it's in `first`

Here's some pseudo-code that should work:

```
sum = 0
current = 1
next = 1
while current <= 4000000:
    if current % 2 == 0 then
        sum += current
    temp = next
    next = current + next
    current = temp
```